# Can't get text to change with a button click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change a line of text, inside a form; more specifically, I want the text to change under certain conditions. The conditions are to check when a user clicks a button. In this case I want text to change when a user leave a input field blank. This code includes the entire form I'm working with and the script. The problem I'm having is the text seem to change when the button is clicked but only for a second or as long as a alert message is up. Afterwards, it goes back to its original text. The line in my script is accessing is the 5th line of code.

```
<div id="userRegistration"> <!--  Registration Form Shell -->

            <form name="registration">
            <div id="leftSideForm"> <!--  Left side of the Registration Form -->

                <span style="color:red">*</span>
                Enter a Username: <input type="text" name="userName" /> <br />
                 <b id="yy">test </b> <br />

                <span style="color:red">*</span>
                Enter Password: <input type="password" name="userPassword" /><br />

                <span style="color:red">*</span>
                Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="cUserPassword" /><br /> <br /> <br />

                <span style="color:red">*</span>
                First name: <input type="text" name="firstName" /><br />

                Middle initial: <input type="text" name="middleName" /><br />

                <span style="color:red">*</span>
                Last name: <input type="text" name="lastName" /><br /> <br />

            </div> <!-- end of Left sideform -->

            <div id="rightSideForm">

                <span style="color:red">*</span>
                Email Address: <input type="text" name="userEmail" /><br />

                <span style="color:red">*</span>
                Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="confirmUserEmail" /><br /> <br /> <br /> <br />

                <button type="submit" onclick="validateUsername()" >Register</button>
            </div> <!-- end of right sideform -->

            </form>

</div> <!-- End of registration -->


<script type="text/javascript">
function validateUsername()
{
var x=document.forms["registration"]["userName"].value;
if (x == null || x== "")
{
document.getElementById("yy").innerHTML = "WHY WON'T YOU WORK GRRRR";
alert("First name must be filled out");
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your question has quite a bit of code. For better help sooner, post a [SSCCE (link)](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not stopping the form submission event.  In your case this can be done via `return validateUsername()` in the `onclick` and `return false` in the `validateUsername` function on failure:

http://jsfiddle.net/rqUdT/

However it would be better to use standard event registration (via `addEventListener` and use the event object's `preventDefault` method to stop the default click behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/rqUdT/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your text substitution is working correctly. However, once you close the alert box, the form is being sent so the page is refreshed.

Change `onclick="validateUsername()"` to `onclick="return validateUsername()"` and add a `return false` to the end of your click handler function.

And once you've got the hang of that, consider using addEventListener() instead of hardcoded Javascript in your form HTML.

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Class/xbBpY/)

it might be easier with jquery and removing the onclick like:

**JS:**

```
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = document.forms["registration"]["userName"].value;
    if (x === null || x === "") {
        document.getElementById("yy").innerHTML = "WHY WON'T YOU WORK GRRRR";
        alert("First name must be filled out");
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<button id="submit" type="submit">Register</button>
```